# XPath syntax for extract last word in the string

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to extract some words from the html document using XPath. 
Syntax `'//div[@class="adsmanager_ads_price"]/text()[3]'` gives me string `Name: Tim`. How can I modify syntax to receive just `Tim`? But I need words after `Name:` because name can be more then one word.

Comment: I am confused by your question title vs. your question text: Do you want to extract the *last word* (i.e. the part after the last whitespace or similar) or the *last words* (as described in your question, the part after the last colon)?

Comment: Actually I need words after ` Name: `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring-after()` for that:

```
substring-after(//div[@class="adsmanager_ads_price"]/text()[3], ':')
```

Will get all information after the `:`

```
substring-after(//div[@class="adsmanager_ads_price"]/text()[3], 'Name:')
```

Will get everything after `Name:`

**NOTE:**
`substring-after()` can only be used in XPath 2.0. If you use XPath 1.0 you should do the substring in your code...

Comment: `normalize-space()` could be used to 'trim' the whitespaces

Comment: It seems I can't use substring-after() or I don't know how to implement it because my code is a part of the software where whole line of code look as following: name=data.xpath('//div[@class="adsmanager_ads_price"]/text()[3]').extract()

Comment: What error do you get? And I believe it should be implemented as: `name=data.xpath('substring-after(//div[@class="adsmanager_ads_price"]/text()[3], "Name:")').extract()`. Also note that `substring-after()` is only available in XPath 2.0. If you are using XPath 1.0 you can't do this and you should handle the substring in your script/programming language...

Comment: Unfortunately It's XPath 1.0 and error is "Invalid XPath"

Comment: @Goran then you should do it in your code instead of XPath

Comment: `substring-after()` is [available in XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after)